# How to set up http proxy for ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

Is it possible to configure ballerina command to use http proxy when searching for the packages?

Doing `ballerina search twitter` fails with the following error message:

`Connection to the remote host failed : connection timed out: api.central.ballerina.io/35.227.97.45:443`

I tried setting up both http and https proxy in `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have the support to configure the ballerina command to use the http proxy when searching for packages in version 0.970.0. But we will fix it in the next minor release which will be in 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

We have added support to configure the ballerina command to use the http proxy when searching for the packages from version **0.970.1**.

You can download the latest stable version 0.970.1 from [here](https://ballerina.io/downloads/). 
The configurations that needs to be added is provided [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-publish-packages/)